# Is there an official name for this type of chart?

Tags: terminology, visualization

I realize this may not really be the right place to ask this, but I can't really think of anywhere else to ask online.

Specifically, the type of chart that I'm wondering the name of would be a series of columns, a series of rows, and the cells for each cross reference would either have nothing, or an "X".

For example, if an automotive company wanted to create a chart of included features on their different offers.

```
Model    | Electric Seats | A/C | Brakes
------------------------------------------
Basic    |                |     |   X
Moderate |                |  X  |   X
Deluxe   |        X       |  X  |   X
```

Or, another example, if a clothing brand wanted to group shirt size by chest circumference:

```
    | 20 | 25 | 30 | 35 | 40 | 45 | 50 
---------------------------------------
XS  | X  | X  |    |    |    |    |    
S   |    | X  | X  |    |    |    |    
M   |    |    | X  | X  |    |    |    
L   |    |    |    | X  | X  |    |    
XL  |    |    |    |    | X  | X  |    
XXL |    |    |    |    |    | X  | X
```

Thanks

Comment: I'd call those tables with boolean (or yes/no) columns, rather than charts.

Comment: It is close to a truth table when you replace empty spaces by F and X by T

Answer (score 1):

This is called a "Carrol Diagram", named after Lewis Carrol, one of the first mathematics to deal with symbolic logic. He's the author of "Alice in Wonderland", but he was also a mathematician.

He felt they were superior to Venn Diagrams because his diagrams were better able to handle the complement of the union of all sets considered ; that is the set "outside" the circles on a standard Venn Diagram.